# Adding a "next" button to FlexSlider2

Tags: jquery, flexslider

I'm looking to make a "next"-button for my Flexslider.

I was browsing through their git at https://github.com/woothemes/FlexSlider and stumbled upon that they added a function in their recent update:

```
$('#slider').flexslider("next") //Go to next slide
```

I added this to my  in my site, and changed the id that triggers the event, yet nothing happens. Any ideas? My script in the head looks like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#flexnext a').flexslider("next") //Go to next slide
</script>
```

And later in the code:

```
<div id="flexnext><a href="#" style="position: absolute; z-index: 9001; right: 300px; bottom: 8px; cursor: pointer; display: block; text-align: center; color: #fff; text-decoration: none;"><img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/_assets/img/forwardbutton.png" alt="Gå frem" /><br />Læs videre her</a></div>
```

Any ideas what I could be doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call `.flexslider()` on the slider, not an anchor tag.

```
$('#flexnext a').on("click, function(){
  $('#flexnext').flexslider("next")
});
```

Or something similar should work.

If you can't make it work, it would be handy to see a fiddle.